# Mapping node doesn't work with normal map

Tags: texturing, node-editor, normal-map, vector-mapping

I want to scale the fabric bumps down and I've heard using the Mapping node is the way to go. However it's not doing anything at all in my case. Plugging it into the bump texture and it's all gone in the render for some reason.

[image: without mapping node on]
[image: with mapping node on]

Here's my .blend file.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10MT2yDEpkYqRXeAbCSkaTTMf9RlqoEV8

Comment: I guess you have to create an Input > Texture Coordinate before your Mapping node, and you plug the UV output of the TC into the Vector input of the Mapping so that Blender understands that it has to use your UV unwrap. By default he knows it but as you added a Mapping you need to be tell him what sort of coordinate he must apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with what you've left off-screen: there is no input going into your mapping node.  Here's how I fixed it:

[image]

Mapping nodes can be used for all sorts of vectors, so they don't make any assumptions about what should go into them if you don't specify.  Texture nodes, on the other hand, try to take a best guess.

Additionally, notice that I specified a UV map for your tangent-space normal map node.

Finally, using mapping nodes with tiling normal maps in Blender is not ideal, because for whatever reason, no one has ever seen fit to provide a tangent input to the Normal Map node.  Appropriate tangents should go through the same mapping process as the UV coords reading the normal map.  For doing things like this, I would recommend using bump maps instead, which Blender handles more cleanly, or to create and edit an extra UV map instead of using a mapping node for the normal map.  http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/ is a free tool that does a reasonable job of converting normal maps to height (displacement, bump) maps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I'm so noob that even when I'm trying to replicate tutorials online I still fail to see things through. These nodes things are still too complicated for me now.

Comment: It's fine, you'll get the hang of it.